# Push Notifications Android. Application not running clarificaiton

Tags: android, push-notification, broadcastreceiver, parse-platform

I'm developing an android app which implements push notifications using parse.

I have a requirement that the app must 'still receive notifications if the app is not running', but what is 'not running' on android? from what I gather there are 3 ways in which an app can 'not run'.

1. using the back button when the app is running
2. going to applications->force quit
3. holding down the back button and clearing the app from the list of recent apps
4. using the home button.

I have a broadcast receiver registered through manifest that fires only if the app has been closed using methods 1. and 4.

Is that how it should work on android? or should my broadcast receiver trigger no matter how the app is closed?

Answer (score 0):

It's the normal behavior, take a look at the doc here :

http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.1.html

Section **Launch controls on stopped applications**

Or here :

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/05/android-broadcast-receiver-change-in.html

Comment: I'm using android 4.0, will that make any difference?

Comment: Starting with Android 3.1 (so with 4.+ it's the same behaviour), even if your app is not running, you will receive the notification, except when you do a "force stop" from the Settings.